# Is there a way to check how scan and fuzz commands work at backend in ZAP?

Tags: zap, fuzzing, security-testing

We have a requirement to know how commands works at backend when triggered via OWASP ZAP Tool.

This will help for data visualizing & interaction with ZAP and UI.

**For example:**

1. Commands like 'active scan'
2. In ZAP Tool we select required site and click on 'Active Scan' action
3. Active scan happens and the result appears in history tab.

Now requirement is to visualize how the commands interact at the background when user clicks on 'Active Scan' from ZAP tool.

How it reads the request, process the data and generate result back in ZAP tool?

Similarly for passive scan and fuzzing.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in a bit more detail? What commands are you talking about, and is this in ZAP or in the target system?

Comment: I updated question with few more details.

Answer (score 0):

The code is all Open Source. Please refer to the two primary repositories:

Core: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy
Extensions: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions

Answer (score 0):

Also see https://www.zaproxy.org/tags/hacking/ and if you have specific questions then its best to add them on the [ZAP Dev Group](https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-develop)